# ArrayList, Collections

Tags: java, arraylist, collection

Tenho uma lista de exercicio sobre ArrayList , mas só a primeira questão já me deixou com varias duvidas :

1. Implemente uma interface com métodos abstratos getNome, getValor, que deverão ser implementados na classe concreta Moeda. A classe moeda deve ter um construtor que inicie os atributos nome e valor da moeda e, além dos métodos da interface, os métodos set. 
   Utilizando ArrayList, implemente um cofrinho de moedas (outra classe) com a capacidade de: 
   -receber moedas e 
   -calcular o total depositado no cofrinho.

A classe Cofrinho deve implementar métodos para:

– Contar o número de moedas armazenadas

– Contar o número de moedas de um determinado valor

– Informar qual a moeda de maior valor

Já fiz essas classes:

Porem acho que talvez a questão esteja mal formulada, se puderem me ajudar .. minha duvida fica nesta parte **Utilizando ArrayList, implemente um cofrinho de moedas (outra classe) com a capacidade de: -receber moedas e -calcular o total depositado no cofrinho.**

```
package Banco;

public class Moeda implements Interface {    
    private String nome;
    private float valor;

    // CONSTRUTOR

    public Moeda(String nome, float valor) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public float getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(float valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

    @Override
    public void getnome() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
    }

    @Override
    public void getnalor() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
    }    
}   

package Banco;

public class Cofrinho  {
    public void recebemoedas(float moeda){ }
    public void moedasnocofre(){}
    public void nmoedas_valor(){}
    public void maiormoeda(){}              
}


package Banco;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayList<Moeda> a = new ArrayList<Moeda>();
        Cofrinho add = new Cofrinho ();
        Moeda moeda1 = new Moeda ("euro", 5.00f);
        Moeda moeda2 = new Moeda("dolar", 3.00f);

        a.add(moeda2);
        a.add(moeda1);

        for(int i = 0; i< a.size();i++){
            System.out.println("Moeda : "+a.get(i).getNome());
        }           
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Acho que sua questão pede para o cofrinho receber um array de moedas, assim como seria na "realidade", apesar de ser mais correto receber uma moeda por vez.

Mude sua classe `Cofrinho` para receber um `ArrayList` de `Moedas` assim:

```
public class Cofrinho  {
    ArrayList<Moeda> moedas;

    public void recebemoedas(ArrayList<Moeda> moedas){
        this.moedas = moedas;
    }
    public void moedasnocofre(){}
    public void nmoedas_valor(){}
    public void maiormoeda(){}              
}
```

Depois na implementação ficaria assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ArrayList<Moeda> pilhaMoedas = new ArrayList<Moeda>();
    Cofrinho cofre = new Cofrinho();
    Moeda moeda1 = new Moeda("euro", 5.00f);
    Moeda moeda2 = new Moeda("dolar", 3.00f);

    pilhaMoedas.add(moeda1);
    pilhaMoedas.add(moeda2);

    cofre.recebeMoedas(pilhaMoedas);
}
```